# How to calculate Apdex score in AppDynamics?

Tags: appdynamics, apdex

I am wondering if there is a way I can use AppDynamics to calculate an Apdex score for my APIs and Apps. If so, what would be the best possible way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you can do this using ADQL / Analytics searches (assuming you have this licensed).

Without specifics I can only give you a general guide:

- Ensure your API / Applications are instrumented - so response timings are captured
- Enable Transaction Analytics (for the relevant Business Transactions / Application)
- In Analytics use ADQL (https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO21/ADQL+Reference) to actually do the Apdex calculation - and create an analytics metric from this per Business Transaction / Application (https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO21/Create+Analytics+Metrics+From+Scheduled+Queries)
- The metric can then be used in any Dashboards / Reports / Health Rule etc or exported using the Analytics API (https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO21/Analytics+Events+API)